where does popular bridges keeps their private key in backend in dapps?
I have an interesting question, that major players of bridges and other dapps, where do they store their private keys at their backend?
I mean what flow do they decide so that only owner of that project have access to that. No devs , no devops, no one else.
I am expecting answer to be both web3 solution as well as web2 solution.

If you take security seriously you will use a Hardware Security Module.
There are small usb devices, full computers and virtual cloud providers.
In my experience some funders use hardware wallets, others a second phone for wallet.

This is also good, "i know a guy" who has an extra computer with nothing but hardhat installed, no web browsers, no apps, nothing that connects to external servers, he also disabled non fundamental services, he uses that pc to manage the smart contracts, he doesn't even share which connection will use when for short periods of time he connects the pc to the internet to do contract calls and only a few selected in the company knows of the existence of that computer, he even rejected the responsibility to look at the mnemonic of the contract owner's wallet to avoid any unplanned circumstances..

If is not in an environment variable (which is kinda of the easiest way to store keys) I'd have it in:
A) A file with permissions, where only the owner can write/read
B) Reference it from another source, with this I mean that you could have an API in an internal server with an access token
This third option does not answer the first question however it is something that you might consider in order to increase the security of your contracts
C) Have 2 factor identification when calling contract functions, ie. require 2 different variables (name them as A and B) to be true before being able to use a specific function, and require a call from a specific address in order to change a specific variable (ie. require the call to be from "X" wallet in order to change "A" and from "Y" wallet in order to change "B")
I'd also use any hashing algorithm in your keys in order to increase the security, ie. I make a contract only callable by a certain address, that given the right hash, it'd call a function in a third contract;
